# Present form based on product type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I was hoping to design product-specific upload forms (this is a continuity question so to have a clear background you will first need to go though my previous question [Form based on Product Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739567/form-based-on-product-types)) and came up with this:-

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" size="6">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="producttype/antivirus.html">antivirus</option>
    <option value="producttype/babyproduct.html">babyproduct.html</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dq2jzhom/

It's a simple selection box supposed to load all categories/subcategories/product via a database. Once a user, say selects antivirus as his product to upload he clicks antivirus and the "onload" property of the select takes the user to a form which was specifically designed for antivirus, same with the other option baby product.

Is it okay to do this way?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any JS code to show? I think you need to do some more reading.

This `value="producttype/antivirus.html"` will definitely not work. I suggest that you look into using javascript to handle this. Here is a tutorial that might help:

[javascript-coder HTML Form Tutorial](http://javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-tutorial-p1.phtml)